# Bash- Sort a file based on a list in another file

Tags: bash, sorting

I know that similar questions have been asked about sorting a file by a specific column, but none of them seem to answer my question.

My Input file looks like

```
OHJ07_1_contig_10   0   500 130 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   500 1000    180 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   1000    1500    171 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   1500    2000    79  380 500 0.7600000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   2000    2500    62  500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   2500    3000    96  500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   3000    3500    76  500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   3500    4000    87  500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   4000    4500    60  500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   4500    5000    64  500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_10   5000    5468    213 468 468 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_100  0   500 459 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_100  500 1000    156 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_100  1000    1314    77  305 314 0.9713376
OHJ07_1_contig_1000 0   500 239 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_1000 500 1000    226 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_1000 1000    1500    238 500 500 1.0000000
OHJ07_1_contig_1000 1500    2000    263 500 500 1.0000000
```

The program that generated it, sorted alphanumerically based on the name in the first column, but I would like to sort it based on a list of names in another file, and keep all the other data. The other file has other information, like contig length in column 2 (this file was produced with samtools faidx).

```
OHJ07_1_contig_25270    888266  96530655    60  61
OHJ07_1_contig_36751    583964  120924448   60  61
OHJ07_1_contig_44057    504884  134192571   60  61
OHJ07_1_contig_21721    415942  87354744    60  61
OHJ07_1_contig_46339    411691  143341916   60  61
OHJ07_1_contig_44022    330441  133783765   60  61
```

Since each name has a different number of entries in the first file, what's the easiest way to deal with this? Preferably using bash

I haven't tried anything because I have literally no way to tackle this.

Comment: please do share what you tried so far

Comment: _I would like to sort it based on a list of names in another file_ What does this exactly mean? Use that order and ditch all the rest not mentioned in the other file?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: How many lines or records do you have? Also, post such data that it matches the _list of names in another file_.

Comment: I would vote to reopen because the problem seems pretty clear (I'm trying to solve the same thing with two lists of words), if OP can provide the expected output based on the two input files (I can guess, but I might be wrong).

Comment: [This](https://gitlab.com/engmark/xkcd-passphrase-generator/-/blob/415943f0858b76f2bad7e84bba61e89feacad65c/sort-by-reference.bash) should help - it's tailored to both files having only one word per line, but should be easy to adapt for your use case.

Answer (score 2):

I would prepend each line of file that determines the order (from now on named index) with its line number, there is a way using awk , I used the answer written here https://superuser.com/questions/10201/how-can-i-prepend-a-line-number-and-tab-to-each-line-of-a-text-file to do this (assuming your index file is named index and data file is named data.txt):

```
awk '{printf "%d,%s\n", NR, $0}' < index > index-numbered
```

in this way you will have in index-numbered a correspondence between the arbitrary words order you decided and numbers.
you can then use a while on file to sort that replaces each first word with index line number, a comma and the rest of line (keeping name) , for example :

```
57,OHJ07_1_contig_46339    411691  143341916   60  61
```

in this way you will be able to sort using the first field, the number, which translates your arbitrary order in a numeric order.

The while which create a new data file with same numbers as above:

```
while read line
do 
   key=$(echo $line | cut -f1)
   n=$(grep $key index-numbered | cut -d, -f1)
   echo $n","$line >> indexed-data.txt
done < data.txt
```

Then you can simply sort your modified data file (indexed-data.txt) using sort and using the inserted line number as sort key :

```
sort -k1 -n -t, indexed-data.txt >sorted-data.txt
```

If you want to hide line numbers on final output you can filter each one out modifying preceding instructions with these :

```
sort -k1 -n -t, indexed-data.txt | cut -d, -f2 > sorted-data.txt
```

Your final output will be in file sorted-data.txt .

I'm sure this is not the best solution, maybe others can answer better than me.